# Best way to see if character is between 0-9, A-F, a-f hex values

Tags: assembly, mips

I am being given an ascii word such as "ABcd1234" and then I store the hex values in the $a0 register. I then want to iterate through each number and see if it is valid, which would be between 0-9, A-F, or a-f. I am able to check if it is less than 0 branch to another part or if grater than f, branch to another part, but my problem is checking if it is in between the other values. Between 9 and A there are 7 invalid characters that if my ascii word contains, I need to branch to an invalid part of my code

Comment: Make a list of expected values, like `"0123456789abcdefABCDEF"` and verify that each value is in the list. That way you don't have to figure out any ranges,

Comment: how exactly does that work out in mips? Would I make an ascii word? How would I even go about checking my value is in that list?

Comment: Alternatively, create a lookup-table containing a boolean for each possible `char`, denoting whether this char qualifies as a hexadecimal digit. (That's how glibc `isxdigit()` does it.)

Answer (score 3):

If you can do the conditional branching you claim, it should not be difficult to do all the checks. Draw a flowchart or write pseudocode. It's not rocket science, just takes a tiny bit of thinking and knowing the ascii ranges.

For example,

```
if (x < '0') goto invalid;
if (x < '9' + 1) goto valid;
if (x < 'A') goto invalid;
if (x < 'F' + 1) goto valid;
if (x < 'a') goto invalid;
if (x < 'f' + 1) goto valid;
invalid:
```

See the code in operation [here](http://ideone.com/EnCNT6).

Comment: So many branches. You could *at least* do something like `if ((unsigned)(x-'0') > '9'-'0') goto invalid;...`.

Comment: I have deliberately kept it simple to show that OP can do it with his existing knowledge. No need to bring in and explain unsigned comparisons and 2's complement arithmetic here.